# Microsoft Access IF statement

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

I was wondering if you can make an `if` statement in Microsoft Access.

The idea is you have 2 columns. 1st one is called "Quantity" (type is number) and 2nd one is called "In stock" (type Yes/No) and want to make the statement:

> *"if quantity > 0 then "In stock" should be tick otherwise no tick."*

I was trying:

```
iff([quantity] = 0, [in stock] = "No", [in stock] = "Yes")
```

also tried this

```
iff([quantity] = 0, [in stock] = false, [in stock] = true)
```

Hopefully you get it, can someone help or tell me if its possible to make this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's IIF not IFF but it doesn't work like this. IIF is a function, it generates a value but it can't change a field. To do that you would need to run an update query. What you can do, in an unbound control in a form, or a new column in a query is =IIF([Quantity]=0,TRUE,FALSE)  and then label that control/new column as "In Stock" but then it isn't a field it's a calculation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a version of MS Access which offers the Calculated field type, this task is relatively simple and does not require queries or code.

Simply configure your `In Stock` field to be a **Calculated** field, calculated using the expression:

```
[Quantity] > 0
```

Set the **Result Type** to `Yes/No` to indicate that the result will be that of a Boolean field.

The **Format** may be set as appropriate for your application (`Yes/No` I would assume).

Comment: Its 2007 version and the "Calculated field" is not there :(

Answer (score 0):

all editions of Microsoft Access support calculated values in queries.  It is a matter of implementing it correctly.  i.e.:

In Stock: iff([quantity] = 0, "No", "Yes")

This is put in and creates the new field: In Stock

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't use the IIf function to change the value of a checkbox or a bound control.

If what you want to do is simply determine which item/product is in stock and which isn't, you don't actually need have any field such as the [In Stock] field to be in the table. A more elegant method is to simply evaluate the Quantity field and use an unbound text box to display Yes or No.

Set the unbound textbox's control source to:

```
=IIf([Quantity] > 0, "In Stock", "Out of Stock")
```

A slight alternative is:

```
=IIf([Quantity] > 0, "Yes", "No")
```

In the case of the slight alternative above, you change the label  or header label of the unbound textbox to "In Stock". This way, the Yes or No that will be displayed for each product will make sense to all users and viewers. Please note that the equal sign (=) is part of what you will type.

If for some reason you need to store the [In Stock] field as as a Yes/No data type in the underlying table and you want to update this value to Yes or No (tick or untick), then you could use a macro. In this macro, you would use the traditional If Then Else statement together with the SetValue action. I can't post screenshots/illustrations at the moment because I am currently using a phone. The statement will be as follows:

```
If [Quantity] > 0
Then SetValue [In Stock] =Yes
Else: SetValue [In Stock] = No
```

NOTE: you could also subtitle 1 for Yes and 0 for No.